# Using Credits Options In Highcharts with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, credits

I am Learning how to work with highcharts with ASP.NET and I face a problem.
How can I modify the default values of the credits tag.

I am using this code and it works great for me.

```
Chart1.Title = New Title("Titre de la chart")
    Chart1.SubTitle = New SubTitle("ALLAMI Said")

    Chart1.Legend.layout = Layout.vertical
    Chart1.Legend.align = Align.right
    Chart1.Legend.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.top
    Chart1.Legend.borderWidth = 0
    Chart1.Legend.x = -10
    Chart1.Legend.y = 100

    Chart1.ShowCredits = True

    Chart1.YAxis.Add(New YAxisItem() With {.title = New Title("yAxis Titre")})
    Chart1.XAxis.Add(New XAxisItem() With {.categories = New Object() {"1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002"}})

    Dim series = New Collection(Of Serie)()

    series.Add(New Serie() With {.name = "Said", .data = New Object() {400, 435, 446, 479, 554, 634, 687, 750, 831}})
    series.Add(New Serie() With {.name = "Kati", .data = New Object() {120, 220, 320, 420, 320, 420, 320, 420, 500}})

    Chart1.DataSource = series
    Chart1.DataBind()
```

I am showing the credits values with

```
Chart1.ShowCredits = True
```

But it shows the default values for the highcharts Library, How can I modify those values ?

I am waiting for your answers.

Comment: You didn't define what your custom credits are supposed to be anywhere.

Comment: i'm looking for the method to define those lines of code :
`credits: {
            position: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -10,
                y: -7
            },
            text: 'e-Store',
            href: ''
        }`